# Can't install bundle versions properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, surveyor-gem

I haven't used Rails since a year ago and I'm very rusty with the process. I've tried cloning it locally, then running `bundle install`. This is where I run into a suite of errors.

Then I get this error:

```
An error occurred while installing gemname (version), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install gemname -v 'version'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: have you tried downgrading you're `bundler` version ?

Answer (score 1):

The `surveyor` gem last & latest version is `1.4.0` therefore you are getting this error. Check your `Gemfile` and fix the version in it.

You can refer the gem available version [here](https://rubygems.org/gems/surveyor/versions/1.4.0)